How to properly embed a PowerBI report an app using a Service Principal?
I created an Azure Entra app, gave the proper permissions and shared my reports with the account. I followed the following guides for this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-sample-for-customers?tabs=node-js
https://medium.com/@carlosdelgadorojas/lab-testing-an-embedded-report-in-the-power-bi-playground-with-a-service-principal-identity-72c88cbbd488

Now with the tokens proved by the Azure Entra app, I was able to successfully call the following endpoints:

https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token
https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{groupsId}/reports/{reportId}

But unfortunately, to embed the report, the most crucial endpoint I have to talk to is this one:

https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/GenerateToken

When I tried to call this endpoint with the same credentials, (With the token returned by https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token), it gives me the following error: PowerBINotAuthorizedException
Can't we embed a power BI report in our own website without providing the username password of a Microsoft user account? How to do it properly?

Lmk which frontend language you want to use while embedding report?  Angular, React, .NET, Java, NodeJS?
